# Java - interface -instsnceof

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, implementation, instanceof

How can this be legal? A is not implemented by Intf. Therefore how could it be legal to use as this?

```
    interface Intf {
}

class A{
}

class B{}

class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();
        System.out.println(obj instanceof Intf); //Legal - no any errors, just output false
        System.out.println(obj instanceof B);  // Illegal - compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? Legal to use this as what?

Comment: What is the output of your print line statement? true? false? "illegal"?

Comment: what instanceOf actually do is, it checks your object to particular class or interface,
So what is the meaning of legal here?

Comment: @deHaar  output would be false, because obj is not an instance of Intf

Comment: I know ;-) I wanted to have an answer from @kasun … His code is legal because he just checks something and prints the result. `A` does not implement `Intf`, so the result must be false.

Comment: @kasun this code will run _(legally)_ because the class `A` was declared, not yet implemented, therefore when you create the `obj` and you ask this object `obj` is `instanceof` `Intf`? the result will be `false`. The problem will be if you want to use a function or attribute like `obj.color` this will raise an error and your code will not run. Why? because you didn't declare the attribute `color` in the class `A` therefore the object `obj` will not be able to use it.

Comment: Question code - edited

Comment: `instanceof` keyword is a binary operator used to test if an object or instance `obj` is a subtype of a given type in this case a class `B`. What means this? well means that if the type cannot be converted by casting conversion to the target type specified by the cast operator, then a compile-time error occurs. But why the interface `Intf` was converted by casting? Well this is because the interface behave differently allowing multiple inheritance this means any subclass of `A` may implement `Intf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JLS 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) states:

> If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)), then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true.

In this case `(Intf) obj` is not a compile time error because [JLS 15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) states:

> If the compile-time type of the operand cannot be converted by casting conversion ([§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)) to the target type specified by the cast operator, then a compile-time error occurs.

So why is the cast not a compilation error?

Because while the static type of `obj` is `A`, the actual could be `A` or any subclass of `A`.  And subclasses of `A` *could* implement `Intf` !!

Now we can see that is impossible in this context because `obj` has been initialized with a reference to an `A` instance .... but the type checker is not permitted to make that logical inference.  (Or at least if it does, it can only treat it as a Warning not an Error.)

Comment: Wow. Thatz perfect answer. Thank you